# Gulp-imagemin error?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-imagemin

First time I am using gulp.In my gulpfile.js contains

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
gulp.task('default', function () { console.log('Hello Gulp!') });
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
   var img_src = 'src/images/**/*', img_dest = 'build/images';

   gulp.src(img_src)
   .pipe(changed(img_dest))
   .pipe(imagemin())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(img_dest));
});
```

When running Git bash from my woking folder as
$ gulp imagemin

But it shows the following error

```
[11:35:12] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\work\gulpfile.js
[11:35:12] Starting 'imagemin'...
[11:35:12] 'imagemin' errored after 10 ms
[11:35:12] ReferenceError: changed is not defined
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\work\gulpfile.js:8:10)
    at module.exports (C:\xampp\htdocs\work\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\xampp\htdocs\work\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\xampp\htdocs\work\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\xampp\htdocs\work\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\58_user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
```

How can I rectify this issue? Please help me. Can anybody provide gulp installation guidlines for angularjs. Thanks in advance

Comment: you have not defined `changed ` gulp task.

Comment: How can I define that? Can you give me a example?

Comment: `gulp.task('changed', function() {});`

Comment: How can I put that in the gulpfile.js? Please..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `changed` ?

Comment: I just wanted to compress image.Is change function is neccessary for that?

Comment: NO, you can remove it

Comment: @RahulKR if nikky solved your problem, you can mark her answer (below) as "accepted" by clicking the √ on the left of her anwer. more tips on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and an explanation of why it helps [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
gulp.task('default', function () { console.log('Hello Gulp!') });
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
   var img_src = 'src/images/**/*', img_dest = 'build/images';

   gulp.src(img_src)
   .pipe(imagemin())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(img_dest));
});
```

remove unnecessary undefined task `changed`.  `.pipe(changed(img_dest))`.

Answer (score 1):

**Other easy solution, If u want to use require() is simply change the
version**

## Note

**[don't use .pipe(changed())]**

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-imagemin@7.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i gulp-changed --save-dev
```

Add this line of code after `var gulp = require ('gulp');`:

```
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
```